# Do I need to commit a code if doing an insert before an update?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following SQL:

```
INSERT IGNORE...
UPDATE ITEM...
```

Do I need to do a conn.commit() between the two statements? Or can I commit everything at the end, and the update will automatically pick up on the items that are 'staged for commit' in the SQL?

```
self.cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO main_catalog (apple_id, provider_id) VALUES (%s, %s)', (apple_id, provider_obj))
self.conn.commit() # IS THIS NEEDED HERE?
self.cursor.execute('''UPDATE main_catalog SET 
                       show_title=%s, artwork_apple_url=%s, title=%s, itunes_url=%s, 
                       network_name=%s, video_length=%s, episode_production_number=%s, 
                       synopsis=%s, date_last_updated_affiliate=NOW()''',
                       (show_title, artwork_apple_url, episode_title, itunes_url, network_name, video_length, episode_production_number, synopsis))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the commit is never *needed* unless you are closing the connection. It can be used between long statements to save the current state and get better performance, but even without committing, the previous modifications are there, they are just not saved to disk until a commit (or even before with the autocommit).

It's not recommended to commit a transient state because between two commits you are in a *transaction*, this means that you can be sure that either all your changes will be done or none, which is normally desirable. So if you don't have any indication that tells you otherwise, commit only stable data.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would you suggest having the commit in the middle then? Or just at the end?

Comment: @David542 it depends if the inserted data are huge it may improve performance, or if your data are really important maybe you want commit often, otherwise just go for a single commit at the end.